# Django 1.6 redirect() causes 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django

I have 2 views...one to modify a database object with `UpdateView`. The other view uses `CreateView` in case the object doesn't exist. I am using a redirect to CreateView if the query find that the object does not exist. However, I get `'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute '_meta'` and can not figure out why.

```
class AccountCreateOrModify():
    model = Employee
    form_class = AccountForm
    template_name = 'bot_data/account_modify.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')


class AccountModify(LoginRequiredMixin,
        AccountCreateOrModify,
        UpdateView):
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        try:
            pk = self.request.user.pk
            query_set = self.model.objects.get(user_assigned=pk)
            return query_set
        except Employee.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('account_add/')

class AccountCreateRecord(LoginRequiredMixin,
        AccountCreateOrModify,
        CreateView):
    print "hi"
```

**EDIT: I have modified AccountModify:**

```
class AccountModify(LoginRequiredMixin, 
        AccountCreateOrModify,
        UpdateView):

def dispatch(self, request):
    try:
        pk = self.request.user.pk
        query_set = Employee.objects.get(user_assigned=pk)
        return query_set
    except Employee.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('account_add')
```

Which works when there is no record. But when there is a record I get

```
Internal Server Error: /account_modify/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 201, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 30, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:
AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Your `AccountCreateOrModify` class is an old-style class (not descended from `object`). This is probably not a good idea.

Comment: thanks, but didn't help my issue

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L21) to understand how `UpdateView` works. The `get_object` method is supposed to return a model instance, hence why you are getting the error since `HttpResponseRedirect` is not a model instance.

Try doing the check in the `dispatch` method instead.

Comment: How can I have def_object() pass the pk to dispatch()?

Comment: You mean `get_object()`..?

Comment: Access it the same way you were, `self.model...`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `get_object()` is just supposed to return an instance. You can't return an `HttpResponse` the way you would with a function-based view.

One approach to this would be to raise a custom exception to signal redirection, and then write a middleware to process that exception and turn it into a redirect. If you're potentially doing redirects in a lot of different places, this can be useful.

Another approach would be to override `dispatch()` (which *does* return an `HttpResponse`) and do your redirect from there.